# Ant to Gradle Migration- exec task

Tags: java, gradle, jar, ant, exec

This below task adds some of the class files to the generated jar in my build.xml and produces output as jar.

Can someone please help me in converting this below entire task to gradle task. I am in process of converting ant tasks to gradle and I am stuck here.

```
<target name="generate-was-deployment" depends="init">
<exec executable="${websphere.home}/bin/ejbdeploy.bat" dir="build">
<arg file="${build}/${component.name}.jar"/>
<arg path="${ENV.TEMP}/deploy"/>
<arg file="${build}/${component.name}-deployed.jar"/>
<arg value="-cp"/>
<arg value="&quot;${deploy.classpath}&quot;"/>
<arg value="-keep"/>
</exec>
<delete file="${build}/${component.name}.jar"/>
<move file="${build}/${component.name}-deployed.jar" tofile="${build}/${component.name}.jar"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task generateWasDeployment {
   doLast {
      exec {
         workingDir 'build' 
         commandLine(['cmd', '/c', "${websphereHome}/bin/ejbdeploy.bat"]) 
         args file("$build/${component.name}.jar") 
         args ... 
         args ... 
      } 
      delete "$build/${componentName}.jar" 
      file("$build/${componentName}-deployed.jar").renameTo(file("$build/${componentName}.jar")) 
   } 
}
```

See

- [Project.exec(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec-org.gradle.api.Action-)
- [Project.delete(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete-java.lang.Object...-)
- [Project.file(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: When I executed above task am getting Cannot cast object 'cmd' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'